# Unreachable code, usage of variables in different classes

Tags: java

I made a loop that creates buttons and at the after that loop any code that I write I get the same error "unreachable code" and now i cant make any additional changes to those buttons. is there any way to add code after that or is it just imposible?

Also I don't understand the int a; in the main that I called st in the Action listener. I want the st to decrease for 1 everytime a cetain button is clicked but it seems to work separetly for each button. I made it so it writes it out on a button each time a press another button to test it and it just incresses by 1 from the first to the last button. (I hope I'm making any sense)

Here is my code,
Main class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Start {
public static int a;
public static JButton [][] gumbi = new JButton[15][15];
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame okno = new JFrame("Nonogram");
    okno.setVisible(true);
    okno.setSize(700, 700);
    okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    okno.add(panel);



    JPanel polje = new JPanel(new GridLayout(15, 15));
    panel.add(polje, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    a = 0;

    for(int i = 0; 0 < 15; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
            if(i < 5 && j < 5){
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                //gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
            }else if(i < 5 || j < 5){
                gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                //gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
                gumbi[i][j].setEnabled(false);

            }else{
                if(Math.random() <= 0.6){

                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                    gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                    gumbi[i][j].setText("3");
                    polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);

                }else {
                    gumbi[i][j] = new JButton();
                    gumbi[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(new Listener(gumbi));
                    gumbi[i][j].setText("4");
                    polje.add(gumbi[i][j]);
                }
            }
            if(gumbi[i][j].getText() == "3"){
                a += 1;
            }
            if(i == 14 && j == 14){
                gumbi[i][j].setText("" + a);

            }
        }
    }
    //unreachable code

}
}
```

Action Listener class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;


public class Listener implements ActionListener {
JButton[][] gumbi = Start.gumbi;
final int number = Start.a;

public Listener(JButton[][] gumbi)  {
    this.gumbi = gumbi;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    JButton gumb = (JButton) e.getSource();
    int st = number;
    if( gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE){
        gumb.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    } else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK){
        gumb.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    if( gumb.getBackground() == Color.WHITE && gumb.getText() == "3"){
        st -= 1;

    } else if (gumb.getBackground() == Color.BLACK && gumb.getText() == "3"){
        st += 1;
        gumbi[0][0].setText("" + st);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Change `0 < 15` to `i < 15`, and learn how to debug your code.

Comment: *"and now i cant make any additional changes to those buttons"* Why not?

Answer (score 2):

For loop syntax

```
for ( {initialization}; {exit condition}; {incrementor} ) {

}
```

initialization - initialize variable
exit condition - specify on which condition your loop will exit
incrementor    - increment value of your variable

In your code you made mistake while writing *exit condition* you should use `variable name < value`. you need to replace `0` to `i` i.e. your variable name.

```
for(int i = 0; 0 < 15; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++){
   }
}
```